# Calculating Test Average using while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, calculation

I have tried using userData. parts, whether it be is numeric or Invalid. I need it to kick back to the code when someone enters a string, but it breaks when entering something. It also calculates invalid numbers into the average and I do not know how to fix that. I need to use a while loop for this assignment, however. Lastly, it needs to end when someone enters "999" and I have done that.

```
avr = 0
NbrScores = 0
totalScr = 0
score = 0

#userDataInvalid = True

while score == score:
    score = int(input('Please enter a test score here: '))
    totalScr += score
    NbrScores += 1
    if score == 999:
        NbrScores = NbrScores - 1
        totalScr = totalScr - 999
        avr = totalScr/NbrScores
        print('The amount of test scores you have entered is:', NbrScores, 'Your average test score is: ', round(avr, 2))
        break
    while score < 0 or score > 100:
        print ('ERROR: The score cannot be negative or greater than 100.')
        score = int(input('Enter a valid test score: '))
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is with your code. Could you clarify what you mean by "I need it to kick back to the code when someone enters a string, but it breaks when entering something"?

Comment: What is the point of `while score == score:`? Is that supposed to be different from `while True:`?

Comment: To handle non-numeric string inputs catch ValueError.

Comment: @jarmod I don't see how `score == score` is supposed to accomplish that

Comment: @BenGrossmann not sure I understand your comment. Obviously the while statement is a less-than-ideal way to write an infinite loop (typically written `while True` as you've suggested in your answer) but I don't understand what that has to do with my comment about catching ValueError.

Comment: @jarmod My mistake, I basically misread your comment as "to handle non-numeric string inputs" in response my second comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that does what I think you're going for.

```
avr = 0
NbrScores = 0
totalScr = 0
score = 0

#userDataInvalid = True

while True:
    try:
        score = int(input('Please enter a test score here: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid score")
        continue
    totalScr += score
    NbrScores += 1
    if score == 999:
        NbrScores = NbrScores - 1
        totalScr = totalScr - 999
        avr = totalScr/NbrScores
        print('The amount of test scores you have entered is:', NbrScores, 'Your average test score is: ', round(avr, 2))
        break
    while score < 0 or score > 100:
        print ('ERROR: The score cannot be negative or greater than 100.')
        score = int(input('Enter a valid test score: '))
```

An example run:

```
Please enter a test score here: 10
Please enter a test score here: a
invalid score
Please enter a test score here: 20
Please enter a test score here: 999
The amount of test scores you have entered is: 2 Your average test score is:  15.0
```

Here's a more dramatic refactoring of your code that I find more sensible.

```
NbrScores = 0
totalScr = 0

#userDataInvalid = True

while True:
    try:
        score = int(input('Please enter a test score here: '))
        if score == 999:
            break
        assert 0 <= score <= 100
    except ValueError:
        print("ERROR: The score must be an integer.")
    except AssertionError:
        print("ERROR: The score cannot be negative or greater than 100.")
    else:
        totalScr += score
        NbrScores += 1
    
avr = totalScr/NbrScores
print(f"The amount of test scores you have entered is: {NbrScores}",
    f"\nYour average test score is: {avr:.2f}")
```

Example run:

```
Please enter a test score here: 10
Please enter a test score here: 20
Please enter a test score here: -10
ERROR: The score cannot be negative or greater than 100.
Please enter a test score here: a
ERROR: The score must be an integer.
Please enter a test score here: 30
Please enter a test score here: 999
The amount of test scores you have entered is: 3 
Your average test score is: 20.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and efficient approach

```
total= 0
no = 0

while True:
    try:
        score = int(input("Please enter a test score here: "))
    except:
        print("Enter a valid test score: ")
    if score != 999:
        if (score < 0 or score > 100):
            print("ERROR: The score cannot be negative or greater than 100.")
            continue
        total += score
        no += 1
    else:
        print('The amount of test scores you have entered is:', no, 'Your average test score is: ', round(total/no, 2))
        break
```

Sample Output

```
Please enter a test score here: 54
Please enter a test score here: 87
Please enter a test score here: 15
Please enter a test score here: 216
ERROR: The score cannot be negative or greater than 100.
Please enter a test score here: 56
Please enter a test score here: 999
The amount of test scores you have entered is: 4 Your average test score is:  53.0
```